# Add margin/focus to a button if a keyboard is shown on ionic3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

What I want to achieve is to either focus or alternatively add a bottom margin to a button after I click on an ion-input and the keyboard shows up, why I am doing this is because the keyboard is covering the button, and the button is actually under the ion-input, which means I will need to scroll the page up after my input.

What I have achieved currently is this:

**page.ts**

```
export class TestPage {

btnfocus: boolean = false;   

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public keyboard: Keyboard) {
  }

    isShowing() {
    if(this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow()){
        this.btnfocus = true;
    }else{
        this.btnfocus = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**page.html**

```
<div class="center" id="pinlayout">
                <label class="center">Enter your 4 digit pin to proceed</label>
                <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
                                <button [style.focus]="btnfocus" class="center" (click)="enterPin()">Proceed</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of thinking I decide to do something like this:

page.ts

```
  export class TestPage {

    btnmargin = "";
    layoutmargin = "";
    newheight = "";

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public keyboard: Keyboard) {
      }

      isShowing() {
          this.btnmargin = "15px";
          this.layoutmargin = "30%";
          this.newheight = "auto";
    }
    isGone(){
      if(this.layoutmargin == "30%"){
        this.layoutmargin = "60%";
      }else if(this.layoutmargin == "30%"){
        this.layoutmargin = "60%";
        }
    }

    }
```

page.html

```
<div class="center" id="pinlayout" [style.margin-top]="layoutmargin" [style.height]="newheight">
                    <label class="center">Enter your 4 digit pin to proceed</label>
                    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
                                    <button [style.margin-top]="btnmargin" class="center" (click)="enterPin()">Proceed</button>
                </div>
```

I don't know if anyone get it, I just change the style on focus or onclick, that's it.

mean while the if statement can be shorten to while statement and it will serve the same purpose, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way I solved this issue was to add a class to the body tag that indicates when a keyboard is open.

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
...

constructor(public keyboard: Keyboard) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(() => {
          document.body.classList.add('keyboard-is-open');
        });

        this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(() => {
          document.body.classList.remove('keyboard-is-open');
        });
    });
}
```

And then in your CSS

```
body.keyboard-is-open {
  button {
    ... add margin ...
  }
}
```

---

There are issues with the keyboard that covers input.
Another way I fixed this was to change the keyboard setting to sit on top of the page and not move it up.

In AndroidManifest.xml I change the windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: It's not working for me, anyway I have found a solution similar to this current one, I will post it now.